# how to call another intent from countdown timer finish method?

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, scoring

I am working on android quiz. In my code i have countdown timer when time finish i want next question came and score are decreases (for score decrement currentGame.decrementScore() method). If i add folowing code in timer's finish() method. Its work properly but then my exit button not works properly. When i click on that dialog box appears on pressing yes its remain on current page. After pressing it 3-4 times its exit from current activity and goes on menu page. Then from menu page game starts without pressing play button automatically.

```
code for my class:-
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
                /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
        nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));

        int score = currentGame.getScore();
        String scr = String.valueOf(score);
        TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        score1.setText(scr);

        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView timers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
                timers.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() { 

                                   }
         }.start();
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.answer5)
        {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Are you sure?")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
         int id) {
                finish();
                 }
             }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

                }

        else
        {
            if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
          }
        }
      }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {

        Button b=(Button) v;
        String answer = b.getText().toString();

            //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
            {
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answercolor);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                currentGame.incrementScore();
            }
            else{
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answercolorr);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                currentGame.decrementScore();
            }
            return true;
        }

}
```

And code i am adding in finish method of a timer:-

```
intent i; 
i.setClassName("com.pkgname","com.pkgname.classname"); 
startActivityForResult(i,0);
```

Comment: *After pressing it 3-4 times its exit from current activity and goes on menu page* seems that you have many activity stacked up, provide code for exit button.,, if you are calling same activity over and over again make sure to finish current activity before calling next..

Comment: i added. you can see now.

Comment: I don't know if this might help,, try calling `finish()` first and then call your activity...

Comment: I already tried that thing not working.

Comment: Well, Your issue is  **same activity got piled up**, so a work around instead of calling same activity again, try refreshing its content, in other words, put the content of your `onCreate()`  inside a new method and try calling that method instead of calling new activity...

Comment: can you explain me with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new method say `processScreen()` and insert data of `onCreate` inside it so that you can call this method, repeatedly with having to call same activity again..(its a workaround..)

```
private void processScreen(){
        /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
        nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();
}
```

so now your `onCreate` becomes

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
        processScreen();
}
```

Now, call `processScreen()` instead of calling `QuestionActivity` again in `onClick` of your button. In other words, contents will be refreshed..

Hope this helps..

Comment: Excellent answer bro. but how to call currentGame.decrementScore() method here to decrease score when timeup?

Comment: one problem now my quiz work for only 8, 9 or 10 round and app stop working.. but i set 20 rounds before. and before adding this code its work for 20 question.

Comment: Plz debug and find out why is this behaviour, I dont think this will be a major issue,.. simple logic prob in your code...

Comment: ok bro. but i want to decrease score when times up and in my code currentGame.decrementScore() method to decrease score. where i have to add and what code for this?

Comment: can you help me on this link?     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720544/how-to-save-score-on-server-side-with-different-ids

Comment: bro. i need your help. please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800528/unable-to-solve-errors-in-android

Comment: i have one issue when i type password its show that digit or alphabet then convert it into dot. i want i press any digit its not show that digit or alphabet show only dot.