# Unable to solve errors in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, runtime-error, android-logcat

I am working on android quiz game. QuestionActivity and EndgameActivity are 2 classes in my game. I want when my game over control transferred to EndgameActivity. For this in QuestionActivty class i add

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
```

in `if(currentGame.isGameOver())` method. But after answering last question when my game over control not tranferring to EndgameActivity and log cat showing following errors.

QuestionActivity Class-

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;
    private CountDownTimer counterTimer;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.question);
                processScreen();
         }
                /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
         private void processScreen()
         {
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
        nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));

        int score = currentGame.getScore();
        String scr = String.valueOf(score);
        TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        score1.setText(scr);

        counterTimer=new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {                
                if(currentGame.getRound()==20)
                    System.exit(0);
                currentGame.decrementScore1();
                processScreen();
                             }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
                time.setText( ""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                }
        };
        counterTimer.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.answer5)
        {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Are you sure?")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
         int id) {
                finish();
                 }
             }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

                }

        else
        {
            if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
            else
            {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(i);
        }
        }
      }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {

        Button b = (Button) v;
        String answer = b.getText().toString();
         counterTimer.cancel();
         b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans);
         b.setEnabled(false);
                    //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
            {
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansgreen);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                currentGame.incrementScore();
            }
            else{
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansred);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                currentGame.decrementScore();
            }
            return true;
        }

}
```

EndgameActivity Class-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EndgameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button menue1, adde1;
    TextView escore1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.endgame));
        menue1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.menue);
        menue1.setOnClickListener(this);
        adde1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adde);
        adde1.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             switch(v.getId()){
                 case R.id.menue:
                     Intent i= new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
                     startActivity(i);    
                     break;
                 case R.id.adde:
                     Intent j = new Intent(this, HighscoreActivity.class);
                     startActivity(j);                   
                 break;

             }
         }

    }
```

Log Cat-

```
   09-09 18:32:14.668: D/AndroidRuntime(7617): Shutting down VM
09-09 18:32:14.668: W/dalvikvm(7617): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=EndgameActivity }
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at com.abc.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:143)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-09 18:32:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(7617):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 18:32:18.258: I/Process(7617): Sending signal. PID: 7617 SIG: 9
09-09 18:32:18.758: E/Trace(7693): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-09 18:32:18.908: D/dalvikvm(7693): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 8% free 2413K/2616K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
09-09 18:32:18.918: I/dalvikvm-heap(7693): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.553MB for 2160016-byte allocation
09-09 18:32:19.038: D/dalvikvm(7693): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 4521K/4728K, paused 113ms, total 113ms
09-09 18:32:19.088: D/dalvikvm(7693): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 4521K/4728K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 50ms
09-09 18:32:19.558: D/gralloc_goldfish(7693): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-09 18:32:21.728: I/Choreographer(7693): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Menifest File-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.abc.cyk"
      android:versionCode="3"
      android:versionName="3.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/cyk_icon_bg" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".CYKApplication" >
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".QuestionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".RulesActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".EndgameActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".HighscoreActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".AnswersActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" />

</manifest>
```

I think maybe some error in timer method that cause these errors. Anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: check your manifest file if you declared the activity there

Comment: May be you are missing register or declare activity in Manifest file..

Comment: I already added that in menifest file.

Comment: @Raghunandan Any other solution?

Comment: @JohnR where is you on click method?

Comment: In QuestionActivity my on click method. you can check in that class i also added dialog box in on click method.

Comment: @Raghunandan i edit code and maybe the reason i am facing. please help me.

Comment: Is your EndgameActivity inside package com.abc.cyk??? try giving fully qualified name in Manifest file like for eg:- `com.abc.yourpackage.EndgameActivity`

Comment: @JohnR is your `EndgameActivity` inside `com.abc.cyk` package?

Comment: Search your project for "startActivity". According to the error, you are calling action = "EndgameActivity" which means you used something like `startActivity(new Intent("EndgameActivity"));`

Comment: @JohnR Just to point it out, my answer below suggested the same solution more than 13 hours before the accepted answer. Funny how things work out sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am going through your code, remove `findViewById` from your code

```
setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.endgame));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Check your manifest file you register activity
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {     act=EndgameActivity }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that your `EndgameActivity` cannot be found. The exception:

```
ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=EndgameActivity }
```

tells you that `EndgameActivity` is somehow being treated as an action. This is odd because you are neither using the constructor Intent(String):

```
Intent i = new Intent("EndgameActivity");
```

Nor using Intent#setAction(String).

Try using the fully-qualified class name:

```
Intent i = new Intent(com.abc.cyk.QuestionActivity.this,
                                            com.abc.cyk.EndgameActivity.class);
```

Another thing you can try:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(QuestionActivity.this, com.abc.cyk.EndgameActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Although its unrelated to your current issue, I noticed that in EndgameActivity#onCreate(Bundle), you're using:

```
setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.endgame));
```

This should be changed to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.endgame);
```

Answer (score 0):

Addyour EndGame Activity in the manifest file. Logcat clearly says

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=EndgameActivity }
```

Just add the EndgameActivity in the manifest file inside a new activity tag.